# how to get the path of current exe in addition to using readlink in Linux?

Tags: c++, path

To get the path of current executable, we have used the following code:

```
char result[PATH_MAX + 1];
ssize_t count = readlink("/proc/self/exe", result, PATH_MAX);
if (count == -1)
return false;
result[count] = 0;
```

In addition to using `readlink`, I think another probable way is to use `fexecve`

```
int fd = open("/proc/self/exe", O_RDONLY);
fexecve(fd, argv, envp);
```

But I think `fexecve` only return the error information if there is an error. Is there any way to receive the path from executing `/proc/self/exe`?

Comment: Have you tried argv[0]?

Comment: Those two snippets do two different things?